# BindingSource Filtering

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-5

I have a `DataTable` which have one of its columns as a compound column, multiple integer ids delimited with commas
Example:

```
Col3,Row1: '1,56,75,86,984,1886'
Col3,Row2: '5,77,461,1812,1844,1887'
Col3,Row3: '547,563,754,867,1944,2219'
```

This `DataTable` is the `DataSource` of a `BindingSource` which is `DataSource` of my `DataGridView`.
What is the expression of the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource` to show, for example, only the Row which contains the Id=86?

```
BndGridSource.Filter = $"MyCol = '{MyProperty}'"
```

The above code does not help because if MyProperty = 86 the filter will return both Row1 and Row3, and I want only Row1.

Comment: There's no direct way to accomplish that. See duplicate for how to filter the data itself. If you really want to use the `Filter` property, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression for supported syntax. In your case, something like `"MyCol LIKE '86,*' OR MyCol LIKE '*,86,*' OR MyCol LIKE '*,86'"` might work, though of course only for data where you're guaranteed to have two more values (i.e. there are in fact commas in the data).

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to filter the data itself, so it is not a duplicate post. Because I saw filtering bindingsource is fast than rebuild all datasource of my datagridview.
Meantime, I found myself exactly your solution in your comment :) 
Thanks!

Comment: I found that the filter formula is incomplete, because if record does not contains commas (a single id) the filter is not correctly executed. So I've implemented  `IIF()` function, as `MyCol Like IIF(MyCol LIKE ',', '{MyProperty},%', '{MyProperty}') OR ....` .